# How can 3D Rotation be achieved using Quaternions?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, quaternions

I was trying to implement a Solar System scene in opengl using c++, and I'm not new to it so I already understand how regular rotation of 3D objects works, however this time I wanted to experiment with Quaternions, I've papers on them and how to implement rotation using this formula (Where P= object position vector)-> R= qpq^-1; , but its still not givng me proper results.

Below is the bit of code that is relevant to this question:

```
  NEX_MATRIX::vec<float>Rotation(3);
        Rotation.arr[0]=0.5f;
        Rotation.arr[1]=0.5f;
        Rotation.arr[2]=1.0f;
    NEX_MATRIX::vec<float>Translation(3);
        Translation.arr[0]=1.0f;
        Translation.arr[1]=1.0f;
        Translation.arr[2]=-200.0f;
    
    Projection= Operations.set_Perspective_Projection(Operations.Radians(45.0f), float(SCR_WIDTH)/float(SCR_HEIGHT), 0.1f, 100.0f);
    float projection[4][4];
    View= Operations.Translate(View, Translation);
    float view[4][4];
    
    Model= Operations.Rotation(Model, (float)glfwGetTime(), Rotation);
    NEX_MATRIX::Quaternion<float> Q(0.5f,0.5f,1.0f,float(45.0f));
    
    float model[4][4];
    //implememt orientation quaternion around model matrix diagonal and rotate from other quaternions from there;
  

    //Model= Operations.Rotate_With_Quaternion(Model,Q);
    
    
    
   // Model= Operations.Translate(Model, Translation);
    
    NEX_MATRIX::vec<float>svec(3);
    svec.arr[0]=0.2f;
    svec.arr[1]=0.2f;
    svec.arr[2]=0.2f;
    Model= Operations.Scale_Matrix(Model,svec );
    
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
  
            projection[i][j]=Projection.mat[i][j];
            view[i][j]=View.mat[i][j];
            model[i][j]=Model.mat[i][j];
           
        }
    }
    
    glm::mat4 Views(1.0f);
    Views=glm::lookAt(cameraPos, cameraPos+cameraFront, cameraUp);
    
    sun_shader.Use(1);
    sun_shader.setMat4("Projection", projection);
    sun_shader.setMat4("View", Views);
    sun_shader.setMat4("Model", model);
    
  
   
  //  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
  //  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
  //  sun_shader.SetINT("Tex", 0);
    
   
    
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, (unsigned int)size);
    
    planet_shader.Use(1);
    planet_shader.setMat4("Projection", projection);
    planet_shader.setMat4("View", Views);
    glm::mat4 models(1.0f);
    float x=cos(glfwGetTime())*170.0f;
    float z= sin(glfwGetTime())*160.0f;
    models= set_planet_orbit(models,x , 1.0f,z);
    models= glm::scale(models,glm::vec3(0.2f));
  
    
    planet_shader.setMat4("Model", models);
    planet_shader.setVec3("Color", glm::vec3(0.9f,0.1f,0.2f));
    
    glBindVertexArray(vao2);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0,size2);
    
    
    //draw 2 planet
    glm::mat4 model2(1.0f);

      model2= glm::scale(model2, glm::vec3(0.1f));
  
    x=cos(glfwGetTime())*1500.0f;
    z=sin(glfwGetTime())*1200.0f;
    model2=set_planet_orbit(model2, x, 0.0f, z);// glm::translate(model2, glm::vec3(cos(glfwGetTime())*1500.0f,0.0f,sin(glfwGetTime())*1200.0f));
  
    
    planet_shader.setMat4("Model", model2);
    planet_shader.setVec3("Color", glm::vec3(0.7f,0.4f,0.5f));
    
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, size2);
    
    
    
    
    
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    
}
Delete_Sphere(vao, vbo);
Delete_Sphere(vao2, pvbo1);
glDeleteTextures(1, &texture);

glfwTerminate();


return 0;


}
```

[This is the Quaternion Class Implementation](https://pastebin.com/NfQ7UQ2N)

Comment: When you say it is not giving proper results, what do you mean?

Comment: What happen is that your quaternion class is not correct. Try to use a well tested quaternion class. If you want to implement yours, take the others as reference and test results against those. Here is an implementation from Microsoft (easy to follow and understand): https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Numerics/System/Numerics/Quaternion.cs and here is how to use it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57185542/3d-rotation-using-system-numerics-quaternion/57189284#57189284

Comment: Thank you ,Maurico , and codetiger I meant that the rotation just isn't working sorry for being so blunt.